# incorrect filesystem path running oozie script from terminal

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, oozie, oozie-workflow

So I have defined an oozie workflow in Cloudera that is supposed to move a file "`/user/petter/file.txt`" to another location on HDFS.
I have then defined job.properties as: 
```

```
emailTo=petter.hultin@blabla.com
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs:///user/petter/workflowdef.xml
oozieLauncherJavaOpts=-Xmx1500m
```

I run from the terminal:
*`oozie job -oozie http://oozienode:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run`*

but the job fails with
*

> Cannot access:
>   /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1452553957.19/hdfs://${nameNode}/user/file.txt

*

How do I specify the absolute HDFS path for an oozie script? I.e so that it doesnt look into `/user/hue`...?

The workflowdef.xml is:
```

```
<workflow-app name="blabla" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="fork-7f89"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="fs-8f6b">
        <fs>
              <move source='hdfs://${nameNode}/user/petter/file.txt' target='/user/petter/anotherlocation/file.txt'/>
        </fs>
```

```

Comment: I guess, you have not defined the "nameNode" value in your job.properties

Comment: Add like nameNode=hdfs://foo:9000 in your job.properties

Comment: @AmitKumar well, the problem is that when I run the oozie job from the terminal it adds this extra search path for the workflow. So its adding this "/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1452553957.19/" in front of the absolute path in HDFS that I've specified. 
If I execute the job via the workflow editor on cloudera it runs smoothly. 

(But just to make sure I tried your solution, but with no success)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?